# Unable to make responsive search bar and dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make  Advance search bar. I am using this template https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2q81r.Everything is working fine only problem is, Search bar and dropdown menu is not full width 100%.I want dropdown menu cover full width of search bar and must be responsible.
In this template width of search bar and dropdown is fixed in pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Only delete or comment the width property

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #adv-search {
    /* width: 500px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
    position: static !important;
  }
  .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    /* min-width: 500px; */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having something like:

```
searchbar{width: 500px}
```

Try using max-with to make it responsive:

```
searchbar{max-width:100%}
```

For the dropdown menu add:

```
.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
width: 100%;
//rest of code}
```

Comment: Search bar 100% is working but width of dropdown menu is not full width of search bar neither not responsive

Comment: @RahulKumar check the edit, this should ensure that the dropdown is consistent with the search bar

Comment: Not working, drop down menu width is not managing according to search bar.

Comment: @RahulKumar did you edit the code to have the width: 100% in both instances of the dropdown menu section in CSS? In the link you shared, their css has a .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu at the top of the file and again at the bottom of the file